# Storing and using the Firebase Auth Token for API calls to my server

Tags: firebase, react-native, rest, firebase-authentication

I implemented Firebase [Phone Auth for SignIn](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth) in my ReactNative project. Now I want to use this [JWTToken](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth/idtokenresult) to be passed to the API calls that I make to my server.

And at the server side, I would be validating the token which was passed through the API calls and respond with the proper response. My question is, how can I pass this token in the API calls that I make to my server?

1. I can store the token (within my first loading screen of the app, where it authenticates the User) in the localStorage and fetch it later in any of my screens to make the API calls
2. I can access the Token directly my importing the firebase package in each and every screen (from which am planning to do the API calls) like this: [https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth/idtokenresult](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth) and pass it in the API calls

But I was thinking about storing the Token (fetched during the loading screen) in a global variable inside my ReactNative project and that can be accessed from any screens. But I couldn't find how this can be done? Or which one would be the more appropriate way to do this?

---

**EDIT:**

This is how am getting the Token :

```
  auth().onIdTokenChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      
      user.getIdToken().then( token => {
        console.log( token )
      });

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the token in local storage is not going to work out well for you in the long run.  ID tokens expire after 1 hour, and will not successfully verify on the server after that.

Each individual page should set up an ID token listener so it can use the most fresh token provided by the Firebase Auth SDK.  The SDK will automatically refresh it and provide you with the latest token in the callback.  Every time the token changes, you should use that value in your API calls.  Use [onIdTokenChanged()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged):

```
firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in or token was refreshed.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. So I should display a loader when the page is shown, and inside this `if(user)` body, I should hide loader and the make the API calls. Right? Also, I tried accessing the toke using the `getIdToken()` as well as `getIdTokenResult()` functions on the `user`. But it's returning this: `{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}` always!

Comment: Never mind about the token issue mentioned in my previous comment. I got it working: `user.getIdToken().then( token=> { console.log(token) } )`

Comment: Sure, it's up to you to determine what to display while you're gathering information.

Comment: Thank you. What would be the proper way if I was implementing my own JWT authentication instead of Firebase? I mean where should I store the token in my ReactNative project?

Comment: I don't know - that sounds like a completely different issue.  Please post a new question to describe what you're hoping to accomplish.